# How to add s3fs, UpSetPlot, Matplotlib as AWS lambda layer?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to add s3fs, UpSetPlot, Matplotlib python libraries to lambda layer but due to size limit unable to add it. Tried with S3 upload of ZIP file but that also exceeding limits. The requirements.txt is like

```
matplotlib==3.3.4
mpld3==0.5.5
s3fs==2021.8.1
UpSetPlot==0.6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The [quota](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html) of Deployment package (.zip file archive) size is:

- 50 MB (zipped, for direct upload)
- 250 MB (unzipped)
- 3 MB (console editor)

It seems your zip file size is around 40MB, so [using CLI direct upload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-package.html#gettingstarted-package-zip) will work.

Besides, for Deployment packages over 50 MB:

> If your deployment package is larger than 50 MB, we recommend uploading your function code and dependencies to an Amazon S3 bucket.
>
> You can create a deployment package and upload the .zip file to your Amazon S3 bucket in the AWS Region where you want to create a Lambda function. When you create your Lambda function, specify the S3 bucket name and object key name on the Lambda console, or using the AWS CLI.

Comment: My zip file is of 28MB for single library still get size exceeds error while adding layer.

Comment: Are you using CLI? If possible, can you share your CLI command and the error message?